# Specify icon for Android apps on a TV that are different from the ones on mobile devices

Tags: android, android-tv, android-screen-support, amazon-fire-tv

I have an Android app that will run on the Amazon Fire TV as well as mobile devices. I want a certain icon to display on devices that are running on TV, this should be different from the ones when running on mobile devices.

This is what my icon settings in the `config.xml` file look like:

```
<icon density="mdpi" src="../assets/img/myapp/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
<icon density="hdpi" src="../assets/img/myapp/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
<icon density="xhdpi" src="../assets/img/myapp/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
<icon density="xxhdpi" src="../assets/img/myapp/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
<icon density="xxxhdpi" src="../assets/img/myapp/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
```

What is the density for the TV icon? Or how can I set a particular icon to be displayed on devices that are 960x540?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The icons are in the res folder, inside this folder you have the folders:
- ic_launcher
- ic_launcher_round

The default measure for the xxxhdpi icon is 192 x 192 px, put your icon inside this folder.

To specify the start icon, in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application Android: allowBackup = "true"
         android: icon = "@ mipmap / ic_launcher"
         android: roundIcon = "@ mipmap / ic_launcher_round"
         android: label = "@ string / app_name"
         android: theme = "@ style / AppTheme">
```

To know what is the density, width and height of the screen you can use:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = app.getResources (). GetDisplayMetrics ();
         int height = metrics.widthPixels;
         int width = metrics.widthPixels;
         int density = metrics.densityDpi;
```